# Finding active iframe with Selenium

Tags: selenium, iframe

i am trying to navigate a page with Selenium WebDriver, and have the problem, that there are up to 3 iframes in this page, but only one is "active" the others are set on display: none
everytime i move from one page to another, the new page is loaded in another iframe, but it seems there is no pattern to it, so i cant use

```
_driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(index);
```

the iframes look like this :

```
<iframe id="IF0" class="SOMETHING" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="100%" frameborder="0" target="main" src="../myPath/Blank.html" name="IF0" style="position: absolute; border-width: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; z-index: 10;">

<iframe id="IF1" class="SOMETHING" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="IF1" style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1;">

<iframe id="IF2" class="SOMETHING" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="IF2" style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1;">
```

i tried to use By.xpath like

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(_driver, 60);
    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By
            .xpath("//*[@target='main']")));
```

but it didn't work. Is there any other way to find out which iframe is visible without trying to load them one by one using Exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code, instead. It will switch to the **iframe having 'target attribute' as 'main' and 'display attribute' as 'block'**:

```
try{
  WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(_driver, 60);
  wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@target='main' and @display='block']")));
}catch(Throwable e){
  System.err.println("Error while switching to frame. "+e.getMessage());
}
```

### EDIT

Otherwise if at a time only one frame is visible, try this below code to switch to it:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Comment: doesn' work either, interestlingly enough, i always seem to get an iframe, but the wrong one. i am switching to my default content and call a Thread.sleep to compensate for any delay, still i get the old frame ... in the last try i did //iframe[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception ? And, after switching to an iframe what are you trying to do after that ?

Comment: i just get the wrong frame and the exception occures later when i try to access another Element that doesn't exist in this frame.

Comment: Inspect the element, that you want to get, and check the **iframe id** on the top-left of the **Firepath** panel in **Firebug**. You will then get the exact frame to switch to. Also, please try the edited code above under **EDIT** to switch to the frame.

Comment: The problem is, the site is generic, everytime you load a new page, it is loaded in one of the frames in no clear pattern, therefore its not possible to use the id to find the right frame(as it isn't known). The order in the html source doesn't change so its either .frame(0, 1 or 2). Is it possible that the changing of the values of the attribute "target" or "display" can not be recognized by the driver?

Comment: Yes.. it can recognize the **frame having the attribute 'display' as 'block' or 'target' as 'main' or even attribute "src" not blank**. But, the thing is since the **frames occurrence are incoherent**, then probably **each time you have switch to the relevant frame in the new page, before interacting with any element**. Anyways, is this a public site that you are automating? If it is, I'll be glad to look into it if you can give the URL. Thanks

Comment: thank you, but its not public. and yes thats the problem, everytime i try to interact, i have to switch to the default content and then find the iframe which is currently active. when debugging i found that all of the 3 frames have the attribute target set as main allthough it is not visible in the html, maybe because the value isn't changed but the attribute simply not there this time around, i helped myself now with `WebElement currentFrame = _driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]")); ` which had to be adjusted with one space after :

Comment: Awesome.. that's one way to go @Sirim.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the @id, assuming it is constant with:
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("IF2"));
and then switch to it?